# Replace substring in arrays of strings mongodb V4.2 in a large data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection contains large amount of documents like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd5885daslfjslkajfk1"),
    "album" : [ 
        "album:ASDASDA2", 
        "album:YXSFDFDS", 
        "ZXCVZXCV", 
        "DSFGSDFG"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce2ffsdafsdfsdfffsd"),
    "album" : [ 
        "album:1C85gNlh", 
        "album:SfA7HnpW"
    ]
}
```

I want to replace `album:` by empty in strings inside `album` array, How can i do this in an efficient way using mongodb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find and Replace Strings in Documents Efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866930/find-and-replace-strings-in-documents-efficiently)

Comment: `$replaceOne` will support from mongodb 4.4, you should refer this question's answers.